# a quick question about 64 bit pointer values and memory boundaries

Tags: winapi, memory

I'm learning how to work with (reading/writing to) memory - so I have to deal with pointer values and math. For example some process has a base memory address of 0x00007FF786F20000 (and import address table values higher than that when running - some imported Kernel32.dll function is at 0x00007FF832C2E060).
But since laptop I work on has only 8 GBs of RAM and a pagefile of the same size - that value seem to be much much higher than anything in this system - it would be dozens of terabytes if taken at a face value so to speak.

So why is it so high? Or is some arbitrary value added to it? How to correctly interpret its position in memory? I tried googling it but not exactly sure how to word the search correctly so decided to ask for a solution here.

Comment: The address you have are **virtual address** as mapped by the memory manager. The real physical address depends on how the physical memory has been mapped to the logical (linear) address. From your question it seems that the VMM concept is somewhat new to you, but It would be very long to explain here, so, to not reinvent the wheel, I suggest you to read the basics from this Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Read up about virtual memory. The pointer values that you are seeing are not physical addresses; the CPU translates them to physical addresses via a process that is managed by Windows (the operating system in general). Pointer values are intentionally randomized, this prevents certain security exploits.

Comment: Ah now I get it - so basically Windows chooses the virtual memory values/constraints on its own and they are relative only to a process in question (and any processes that relate to it) so I should simply care about virtual memory values as something that exists in a vacuum (so to speak) and base address is really 0 for that virtual memory space and everything else is relative to it. Gotcha.